# How to add files to be commited in GitHub

Tags: github-for-windows

Hello I recently started using github.  I was able to make my first commit and upload my Java projects whole source folder to my only Repo.  Now I have made changes to my files and would like to recommit the same files but after two hours of tutorials I am still stuck.

This is the process I have been doing.

```
Windows 8
Gitbash
 cd ~\javaProjectSourceFolder(lets call it java)
 git init
  initializes
 git add -A
 git status
  nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I realize I am a newb and that I am not able to "add" my files.  Can somebody help me out?

Comment: I'm still getting nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: Tried that as well, same result

Comment: Are you doing `git init` each time?

Comment: I am not, i'll try that and be back w/ results

Comment: To no avail, git init everytime.

Comment: Please share the git log message & git branch message, to know what could have went wrong.

Comment: i'll try to locate those, again, I am a noob at github, it's confusing the piss out of me.  can you point me to the git log?

Comment: do the command `git log` on terminal
it will show you logs messages with each commit ids or pull or push on that branch. to exit press `:q` . Now to see which branch you are on, please do `git branch` in terminal.

Comment: I only have one branch, master

Comment: http://i43.tinypic.com/2h8262g.png

Comment: Then type `git log` & what do you see, please share.

Comment: You have two commits. It means whatever you have done is already committed. to the repository, but local. So better do a `git push origin HEAD` & then you can see your second commit also on git hub web page.

Comment: Okay, that somewhat worked Balram, except a couple of files were changed.  What is HEAD command?  & how can I add all my files again and recommit them??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you are on the right branch. If not then do the following from the terminal on the repository path. You should do your changes to a local branch, that may be the clone of the master. And next time follow these steps.

`git branch` :This will list all your branch. You must see `master` branch over there.

`git checkout master` : This will make you to switch on the master branch.

`git checkout -b local_branch` : This will create a branch with `local_branch` name & then you can add all your code here.

`git add -A` : this will automatically add the files that are even newly created or modified or deleted.

`git commit -m "my commit message` : This way you can do a commit to all changes.

`git pull origin HEAD` : This will update the current branch with any changes (in case of shared repository) You can avoid this as you are the only one working on your only repo.

`git push origin HEAD` : This will push your changes to the remote branch, but it will not merge this to the master unless you either push it to master or try merging from web on git hub.

For more information on each & every command, please refer the treasure [here](http://git-scm.com/book/commands)

Comment: after git checkout -b local_branch, how do I add my code?  is local_branch an actual file in explorer I can copy/paste to?

Comment: Looks like our discussion is more like a chat. Kindly check the email jos.dev@live.com & reply me there.